# Rails 3.1 rake test:profile deprecation warning and empty output files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, profiling

When runnign **rake test:profile** I get:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: read_csv_fixture_files is deprecated and will be
>   removed from Rails 3.2. (called from block in autorun at
>   /Users/hade/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:508)

Unit.rb around line 508:

```
  def self.autorun
  at_exit {
    next if $! # don't run if there was an exception

    # the order here is important. The at_exit handler must be
    # installed before anyone else gets a chance to install their
    # own, that way we can be assured that our exit will be last
    # to run (at_exit stacks).
    exit_code = nil

    at_exit { exit false if exit_code && exit_code != 0 }
    exit_code = MiniTest::Unit.new.run(ARGV)   <------ LINE 508
  } unless @@installed_at_exit
  @@installed_at_exit = true
end
```

Is MiniTest calling this read_csv_fixture_files method? Is this normal behaviour with my setup? How can I remove this?

My environment:

- Rails 3.1.0
- Ruby 1.9.2-p290 with GC-patch

My tests seem to run ok, but my output files are useless. In my output files I only have this line:

```
ActiveSupport::Testing::Performance::Profiler#run
```

But when I run **rails profiler 'User.all'** I get nice console output and output files with some content.

Any help would be really appreciated. I have tried different Ruby versions with GC-patch, but no help there.

Comment: Did you get this working? I've got exactly the same problem, and been trying to figure it out for two days now.

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't. I was able to figure out the delay in my app other way and didn't use the profiler this time.